# Product reviews aren't shared between store views - bug or feature? Magento 2

Tags: magento2, store-view, review

I'm using Magento 2.2.2. and just noticed that product reviews aren't shared between store views. Is this a bug or a feature?

For example my test customer which reviewed many products only sees the reviews on the store view on which the review was created.

Is there a way to share reviews between store views?

Comment: seems like feature to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Magento database, you can find the table `review_store`. This seems definitely like a feature. The Magento concept of store views is to enable the shop to use different languages - why would you want your English reviews in your German store view? That would make no sense.

However, in the backend under Marketing > User Content > Reviews, you can add a review to multiple store views, just like CMS pages or static blocks.

If you need this for every review, it might be best to write a small module and set an observer on the *_save_after event (for example), and add each review that gets saved to every store view.

Comment: You have a point with the multi-language reviews, but what bothers me is that the ratings aren't shared.